# Having Two Different SQL server 2012 in client?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, tabular

Goal:
Having SQL server 2012 with Tabular mode in my client computer.

Problem:
Is it possibly to install another sql server 2012 with tabular mode in my computer when I already have SQL server 2012 with Multidimensional and datamining mode in my client?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to install another instance

> If the underlying computer hardware can support it, you can install multiple instances of Analysis Services on the same computer and configure each instance to use a different deployment mode

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471594.aspx

Answer (score 1):

of course you can, on different instances though:

[image]